# Python development using Docker interpreter

Tags: spacemacs, python, docker

I would like to use Spacemacs for Python development. I've used Emacs for years and still use it for org-mode and other note taking.

At work we develop using Docker based interpreters. This means that everything happens in the container, not just running the program, but also the autocomplete information, linting, error highlighting etc.

Is this possible from Docker? I had a quick look into using a Docker container as a virtualenvironment but it doesn't seem to be a thing.

- [This is the equivalent for PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-docker-as-a-remote-interpreter.html#config-docker)
- I am also told that it is possible in VS code, but I don't use it so don't know how